# angular not binding the response after http call

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-httpclient

I have a misunderstanding about something in angular, this problem repeated with me after I need to render something after the HTTP response.
I built my project with angular 6, and I am using `HttpClient` to request the server and after the response, I do some logic.
and I am using FormBuilder to bind data.
The problem is, after getting the response data I want to bind this data in the template, the data does not render on the page until the user clicks on any control in the page!

I have tried many solutions but still, the problem not solved so after a search I know that HttpClient return an Observable data and it is working async so I trying to await the response but also this not working.

This is my generic HTTP service code :

```
private token: string;
myHeader: HttpHeaders;
constructor(private http: HttpClient, public router: Router) {
    this.token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    // this.myHeader = new HttpHeaders().append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    if (this.token)
        this.myHeader = new HttpHeaders().append('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.token}`);

}

getRequest(endPoint: string) {
    return this.http.get(this.apiBaseUrl + endPoint,{headers : this.myHeader})
        .pipe(
            catchError((err) => this.handleError(err))
        );
}
```

This is the controller code :

```
constructor(private router: Router, private httpService: HttpService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private fb: FormBuilder) {
this.mode = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('mode');
this.form = this.fb.group({
    userName: [null],
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
    roles: new FormArray([])
});

if (this.mode == "new") {
    this.pageTitle = "Add New User";
}
else {
    this.pageTitle = "Edit User";
    this.isEdit = true;
    this.buildEditForm();
}
this.getSystemRoles();
}
//This to build the form if the mode is edit to bind the roles of user
buildEditForm() {
this.httpService.getRequest(`Account/GetUserDetails?serName=${this.mode}`)
    .subscribe((result: any) => {
        if (result) {
            this.form.get("userName").setValue(result.userName);
            let roles = result.roles.split(",");
            for (let index = 0; index < roles.length; index++) {
                this.roles.filter(r => r.name == roles[index])[0].value = true;
            }
        }
    });
}
//Get all roles in the system
async getSystemRoles() {
await this.httpService.getRequest(`Account/GetRoles`).toPromise()
    .then((result: any) => {
        if (result) {
            this.roles = result;
        }
    });
await this.setUserRoles();
}
//Fill the check box control with data 
setUserRoles() {
this.roles.map((o, i) => {
    const control = new FormControl(this.roles[i].value);
    (this.form.controls.roles as FormArray).push(control);
});
this.isLoading = false;
}
```

The HTML code :

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
 <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="userName" class="col-form-label">UserName</label>
                    <input [readonly]="isEdit" type="text" [formControl]="form.controls['userName']"
                        class="form-control" id="userName" placeholder="UserName">
                    <small
                        *ngIf="form.controls['userName'].hasError('required') && form.controls['userName'].touched"
                        class="text-danger font-14">You must include the user name.</small>
                    <small
                        *ngIf="form.controls['userName'].hasError('minlength') && form.controls['userName'].touched"
                        class="text-danger font-14">The user name must be at least 5 characters long.</small>
                    <small
                        *ngIf="form.controls['userName'].hasError('maxlength') && form.controls['userName'].touched"
                        class="text-danger font-14">The user name cannot exceed 25 characters.</small>
                    <small
                        *ngIf="form.controls['userName'].hasError('pattern') && form.controls['userName'].touched"
                        class="text-danger font-14">Your user name must has alphanumerics and numbers only.</small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="!isEdit" class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="password" class="col-form-label">Password</label>
                    <input #password type="password" [formControl]="form.controls['password']" class="form-control"
                        id="password" placeholder="Password">
                    <small
                        *ngIf="form.controls['password'].hasError('required') && form.controls['password'].touched"
                        class="text-danger font-14">You must include password.</small>
                    <small
                        *ngIf="form.controls['password'].hasError('pattern') && form.controls['password'].touched"
                        class="text-danger font-14">Password must be at least 8 characters, one special character,
                        one Capital character, one number.</small>
                </div>
                <!-- <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <small
                        title="Password must be at least 8 charecters,one spechial charecter, Capital charecters, number">Password
                        Stegnth</small>

                    <mat-password-strength #passwordComponent 
                        [password]="password.value">
                    </mat-password-strength>
                </div> -->
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="!isEdit" class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="confirmPassword" class="col-form-label">Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password" [formControl]="form.controls['confirmPassword']" class="form-control"
                        id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                    <small
                        *ngIf="form.controls['confirmPassword'].hasError('required') && form.controls['confirmPassword'].touched"
                        class="text-danger font-14">You must include confirm password.</small>
                    <small *ngIf="form.controls['confirmPassword'].errors?.equalTo"
                        class="text-danger font-14">Passwords do not math.</small>
                </div>
            </div>
<div *ngIf="!isLoading" class="form-row">
                <div formArrayName="roles" *ngFor="let choice of 
form.controls.roles.controls; let i=index"
                    class="col-md-4">
                    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" [formControl]="choice" [checked]="choice.value"
                            [(value)]="choice.value" class="custom-control-input"
                            (change)="onCheckChange($event,roles[i].name, i)">
                        <span class="custom-control-label"></span>
                        <span class="custom-control-description">{{roles[i].description}}</span>
                    </label>
                </div>

            </div>
</form>
```

and finally, the result is the first image until pressing on any control the result will be the second image:

[the first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fX5Kg.jpg)

[the second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pICVP.jpg)

Comment: Can you add the HTML of the part that have problems (userName) ? We currently only see "roles"

Comment: updated, but I think the problem not in this part because this controls binding but the problem in the roles control

Comment: try to reassign the roles array instead of pushing to array.

Comment: What is you are meaning by reassigning array?